# Angular2 + PrimeNG - How to reset dataTable to new Grid results?

Tags: typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a requirement of showing Grid of Prospects for a particular state. I have state dropdown for this purpose. I also have a PrimeNG global search text box over the grid which will trigger the search in grid columns.

The Problem is when I make only search in textbox it is working and when I only change the state dropdown value it is working. When I combine both initially providing a search text and then changing the dropdown value, grid is not rebinded until and unless I fire a event in Text box.

What I need is when I change the state dropdown I want to reset the text box and reset the grid to new results.

Here is the image to show functionality.

[image]